# How to go to the file destination folder using file path in android?

Tags: android, file

I am working with an application which generates QR code image of particular contents. After creating the image, the image is stored in the sd card. My question is, After saving the image when I click the open button it should go to the folder of the saved image. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: do you want to open the folder like a galley??or simplify get the file  only

Comment: I just want to get the file only.

Comment: `File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");` will get that file

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you know the path of the folder where the image is been stored. Then list all the files of that direcotiry in an activity tagging the details of the item in list item. So that its works like a file manager. In short you shoud customize as a default file manager. Hope this piece of code will help you.

```
File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // is directory
    }
}
```

Comment: How to show that particular folder(image saved) to the user when i click the open button.

Comment: You should create a customized file manager. First fetch all the folders in sdcard and filter it to get that particular folder, then show the user only that folder where you are saving the images. This how you can do it.